# Is there any way to access any row of a dataframe by giving in the value of that row a particular column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have to access the index of the 5th largest value present in column 'a'. I sorted the column 'a' but in doing so, the index column was also sorted, so then I made another column called 'Index' and added values from 0-9 in that column. Now, I want to access the index no. of the row where the value of 'Index' column is 4. Can anyone please help me do that?
I also want a more efficient way to solve this problem.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 30, 30).reshape(10,-1), columns=list('abc'))
df.sort_values('a',inplace=True)
df['Index']=[x for x in range(10)]
df
```

DataFrame:

```
    a   b   c   Index
1   1   25  5   0
2   3   28  8   1
8   6   10  2   2
4   7   22  24  3
3   11  3   15  4
7   12  17  18  5
0   19  11  28  6
6   19  21  28  7
9   25  2   5   8
5   26  16  27  9
```

Expected Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because python counts from `0` for 5th index value of sorted column use slicing by `[4]`:

```
a = df.a.sort_values().index[4]
print (a)
3
```

If values already sorted:

```
a = df.a.index[4]
print (a)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you not killing flies with cannons? The problem is that sort_values change your index order? If it is so, use "ignore_index argument or reset_index() function.

```
df.sort_values('a',inplace=True, ingnore_index=True)
```

Comment: As Jezrael comments, Python counts from 0. It would help if you define what is your final goal.